# How to shorten this Google Spreadsheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got a table in Google Spreadsheet like this:

```
Name | Amount
---------------------------
A1        0
A2        1
B1        2
B2        0
```

Now I've got another table like this:

```
Name | Component1 | Component2 | Component3 ...
_________________________________________________________________
A1          20             17             30
A2          10             20             15
B1          17             17             30
B2          123            19             43
```

Now I want a result table like this:

```
Name            |   Amount
________________________
Component1          44
Component2          54
Component3          75
```

So I want a result table that shows how which components you need. The formula for one cell would look like this:

```
AmountComponent1=AmountA1*Component1A1+AmountA2*Component1A2  // And so on...
```

Now I have a table with about 200 Products and about 10 Components. How Can I shorten this formula?

Comment: The AmountCompont3 result is wrong, I think. It should be 55 instead of 75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

Use [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

## Explanation

SUMPRODUCT

> Calculates the sum of the products of corresponding entries in two equal-sized arrays or ranges.

### Example

Assume that the list of the components, starts at A13. Add the following formula to B13 and fill down as necessary. It includes [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) to automatically select the second array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$5,OFFSET($A$8,0,Match(A13,$A$7:$D$7,0)-1,4,1))
```

[Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o4ZhUc48QAJHvHIa5FSaeWSP0rbRuytzgkXxNjFYB5U/copy)